# Cookies generating some random values

Tags: javascript, jsp, cookies

jsp file

```
<% 

               String stateforcookie=request.getParameter("stateforcookie");
               if(stateforcookie != null ) {
               Cookie cookies2 = new Cookie("statecookie",stateforcookie);

               cookies2.setMaxAge(365 * 24 * 60 * 60);
               response.addCookie(cookies2);
               }                  
               String state=request.getParameter("state");
               Cookie[] cookies2=null;
               cookies2 = request.getCookies();
               out.print(cookies2);

               if (state==null) { if(cookies2 != null)
                                    state=cookies2[0].getValue(); }
              if(cookies2[0].getValue() == null) {
               %>

<body onload="po(0);">
<% }else { %>
<body onload="po(1);">
<% } %>

<div id="popup">
<div id="contenttt">
<form method="post" action="home.jsp">
Choose Your State:<input id="popuptext" type="text" name="stateforcookie" />
 <input id="popupclose" type="submit" value="submit" />   
</form>
</div>      
</div>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
function po(i) {

 if(i==1){
 $('#popup').hide("slow");
    }
  else if(i==0){$('#popup').show("slow");}
}
$(function(){   
     $('#popupclose').click(function(){

        $('#popup').hide("slow");

    });

});   
</script>
```

1.Here i'm trying to store a value to cookie, if cookie is null it will popup a window with text box. if the cookie is not null then the popup window will not been shown.

But i'm facing a problem with the line - out.print(cookies2);  It prints:-

> [Ljavax.servlet.http.Cookie;@1d6bff7

1. if(cookies2[0].getValue() == null) throws null pointer Exception.. 
   Even after deleting all browsing data, i'm getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without assigning value to cookie, how you cannot compare when it is null so your popup window will not be executed. For the 1st time cookies2 will be null, it throws null pointer exception

> if(cookies2 != null)
>          {
>        if(cookies2[0].getValue() != null)
>           {}
>       }

I modified your, try the popUp with this.You should use for loop to get value stored in cookies like i done below

```
<% 

           String stateforcookie=request.getParameter("stateforcookie");
      out.println(stateforcookie);
      Cookie cookies2=null;
      Cookie[] cookies1=null;
           if(stateforcookie != null ) {
           cookies2 = new Cookie("statecookie",stateforcookie);

           cookies2.setMaxAge(365 * 24 * 60 * 60);
           response.addCookie(cookies2);

           }

           String state=request.getParameter("state");

           cookies1 = request.getCookies();

           if(cookies1 != null) 
           for (int i = 0; i < cookies1.length; i++) {
               if (cookies1[i].getName().equals("statecookie")) {
                out.println(cookies1[i].getValue());
                state=cookies1[i].getValue();
                session.setAttribute("statecookie",state);
                 break;
               }
             }

           %>
```